# IE8 Bug with min-height and overflow:hidden?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

Check out the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/symposion/P8KBe/7/

in IE8 and then Chrome/Firefox/IE9+. You will notice that in IE8, the inner blue div is sliced off at the edge of the outermost `#slicer` div, despite the fact that it is only `#outer` that is `overflow:hidden`. If I change the `min-height` on #outer to an explicit `height`, the problem goes away.

The example may seem contrived, but only because I've simplified it right down here. I've encountered this in a real project and it's causing a headache because I have limited scope to change the  layout principles being used - there are too many other dependencies. I'm looking for two things here:

1. Is this a known bug listed somewhere? What is the simplest statement of the issue? I still don't feel like I really understand the underlying error that is causing IE8 to get this wrong; it's still not a particularly simple test case.
2. Is there a workaround that doesn't involve changing the styles of `#outer` and `#slicer`? In my real world example these are part of a larger page framework that I'm going to have trouble changing, whereas the `#inner` bit is more readily under my control.

(Update) The original example is very contrived in an effort to be minimal. I have created a new JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/symposion/NDa6U/ that gives a slightly better view of the real-world problem. If you resize the html pane in IE8, you will notice that eventually the green inner content section starts getting cut off incorrectly. What I'm looking for is for this section to remain 100% of the height of the div it's contained in, ideally without having to make any significant changes to anything other than `#innerContainer`. But to be honest, I'd be interested in any solution that preserves the basic layout principle (a bottom section that expands from a defined pixel position to a defined distance from the bottom of the page, but has a min-height) that works in IE8.

Comment: The test case is useful, but it's difficult to know what I can safely change with such a contrived test case. For example, is there a reason that `#inner` must have exactly `height: 120%`? Why not just `height: 500%`?

Comment: @thirtydot Yeah, I'm sorry, I was working to simplify the scenario in which the bug manifested itself, but it had resulted in a rather obscure testcase. I'm open to any suggestions on #inner, but ideally it would be vaguely robust in the face of changes in the specific dimensions. I'll try and construct a more complex example that represents the real world constraints more accurately, and I'll leave the old one there for people interested in elucidating the underlying browser bug.

Comment: @thirtydot Try the new example if you're still interested. It's a bit more realistic and should give you more of a feel for what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/NDa6U/22/?

```css
#innerContainer {
    padding-bottom: 9999px;
    margin-bottom: -9999px;
}​
```

Here's some (relatively) old background information about this technique: http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/combined

From personal experience, it works in all modern browsers with no problems.

Comment: This is good, and although I dimly remember reading that article a long time ago I obviously hadn't taken on board the principle that you're applying here. I've upvoted you because this is a good technique, but I'm holding off accepting the answer because it has one significant downside - it only postpones the problem. If I put any content inside #innerContainer that uses relative sizes (try a div with 100% height, for example), it will still suffer the same problem - it gets cut off as if the min-height property had never been set :-(

Comment: I think I need to see your complete page to help. The test case never seems to quite match with your actual page :)

Comment: You might want to consider using JavaScript (in only IE8) to fix the problem which is evidently the result of an IE8 bug. Do you really need to support the tiny percentage of users who are both using IE8 *and* have JavaScript disabled?

Comment: Actually, it looks like I can work round that by ensuring that the immediate descendants are absolutely positioned if they need to be relatively sized. Awesome, you've helped enormously; I'm not 100% sure yet whether this will work in every situation that I need it to, but it's looking promising and you've definitely done enough to earn an accept!